# Can't cast Fragment to YouTubePlayerFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to use the YouTube Android Player API to create a player fragment in my app, however I can't create the fragment because when I either try:

```
YouTubePlayerFragment frag =
            (YouTubePlayerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
```

or

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerSupportFragment);
```

I get the following errors:

> Invoncertible types; cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment'
>
> Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)

Looking inside the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment class, I can see that it extends Fragment, so based on my understanding it should be convertible to Fragment.
However, I can see that the class `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, while my Activity imports `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`, so perhaps that's why it won't convert.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you enabled Jetifier as per the [migrating to AndroidX documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio)? That's what rewrites `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` into `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it says "android.enableJetifier=true". However, I have the YouTube Player API as a jar file which I added to dependencies and it says it's in read only mode. Maybe that's the reason